# Ubuntu MaaS Juju Openstack with LXD unable to boot LXD containers

Tags: networking, juju, maas

I am grabbing nodes from MaaS and and deploying my Juju bundle, but cannot spawn containers, because whether I tell it to or not, it wants "Network Spaces" data which I cannot turn off, and am thus far unable to provide it.  Here is my status output:

[Pastebin Juju Status](https://pastebin.com/jcyksPKA)

Here is my bundle:

[Custom Openstack Bundle](https://pastebin.com/KFPY4rs8)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, kindof.  Its working now after upgrading the Juju packages to the current Cosmic Stable release versions, removing the maas cloud, and adding it back again fresh.

Spaces are showing up and being honored now.

Comment: Great to hear that you've got this resolved.